# python window access error

Tags: python, pywinauto, windowserror

my goal is get list item of the application
i use pywinauto module

```
import pywinauto
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='#32770')
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle[0])
lv = window.Children()[3]
lv.GetItem(1)
```

this is error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gunhee\Desktop\getlistview.py", line 7, in <module>
    lv.GetItem(1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 354, in GetItem
    remote_mem = _RemoteMemoryBlock(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 86, in __init__
    raise ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 5] access denied
```

i'm administrator of my windows 8.

please help me

Comment: Are you running the command from [an elevated prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: Is it 64-bit application?

Comment: I don't see `pwa_app.start_()` or `pwa_app.connect_()` calls in your code. Did you omit it due to confidential reasons or just forgot to call?

Comment: i use windows8 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 64-bit Python and 64-bit compatible `pywinauto`: [download from github](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) or find any other 64-bit compatible `pywinauto` modification. Just note my version requires pyWin32 extensions which is in ActivePython distributive by default. BTW, you will get more detailed log for RemoteMemoryBlock failures - there are few improvements in this class too.